# Render a texture to a texture in Direct X using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, directx

I am currently rendering an AVI stream as textures and displaying them out to the panel in C# using Visual Studio 2005 with the June 2010 version of the Direct X SDK. I would like to put some text onto the texture as a watermark or a logo on the bottom left. My question is how would I be able to save out the texture with the font watermark onto another texture. I've been looking into render targets, but have had no success with them, unless I am missing a step. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my current code on how I am rendering out the texture and the font.

```
device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255).ToArgb(), 1.0f, 0);

        device.BeginScene();
        {
            device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.TransformedTextured.Format;
            device.SetTexture(0, tex);
            device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 2, verticies);

            text.DrawText(null, "Test", new Point(10, 20), Color.White);
        }
        device.EndScene();

        device.Present();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up SetRenderTarget then SetTexture the texture you want to render on to the render target and render (Remember to set the UVs on the vertices appropriately!).

Comment: Thanks Goz you've come to my aid yet again :)